# Google Sheets: Need way to check if [text string] exists in a cell containing comma-separated text strings

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Here is the Google Sheet, which should be self-explanatory:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WqSXvM2Ocasc9l16i6mETzYumc3iMbxNM0xZeaPvEb4/edit?usp=sharing

As you can see, I am getting a false positive using the SEARCH (and also the FIND) function.

Looks like I need a way to tell the function to only consider a match if the value occurs as an individual value within the comma-separated text string, but I don't know how to best go about it in a robust manner.

Secondarily, I need to count the number of times the value occurs in the text string.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you making us decipher your sheet? Present a clear and concise description of the problem in your question, not in an off-site link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Because it's easier to figure out if you actually click on the link. Already got a great answer and I've updated the sheet with the solution. Cheers

Comment: hiding a problem description in a sheet - and especially one you then change - means the problem and solution are harder for others to find and learn from. Review the Help Center articles on asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(OR(C11=SPLIT(C6,", ",0)),"YES","NO"))
=SUMPRODUCT(C11=SPLIT(C6,", ",0))
```

- C11 Value to be searched in the list
- C6 The List
- SPLIT the list by the delimiter(the comma) and compare with the test value(C11)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out.

Comment: Works brilliantly. I've updated the Google Sheet with your solution. Thanks again that was quick!

PS - I've upvoted your answer but I guess I'm not reputed enough for the upvote to be visible. Sorry about that!